# Why are my circles displaying as black?

Tags: arrays, loops, processing, draw

I'm trying to make a program that creates up to 24 circles in a neat lattice that start off as white, and then as conditions (such as the hammer reaching the bottom of the screen and resetting) are met, changing those circles in order from left to right - going down one row each time the x-axis circles reach the defined edge of their row.

I created an array that holds the 24 colours in its indexes, all set to white ( - the same as the background for invisible circles) at the beginning, but changing one by one with the conditions. However, when I run my code below, I get an unchanging lattice of all black circles from the very beginning without considering the hammer, and the upper-left circle of every seventh row having a little white dot in it (only one visible in the 6-row test run).

I have no clue what caused this, and having scanned the code numerous times, I can't see where black is coming in from at all. The hammerPos if statement is incomplete at this point, as I'm still trying to figure out what's going on.

Here's my code:

```
int hammerPos = 0; int hammerVel = 1; int hammerPending = 0;
int jump = 60;
int pointIntervX = 20;
int pointIntervY = 20;
int pointX = pointIntervX;
int pointY = pointIntervY;
int pointSize = 10;
color white = color(255,255,255);
color black = color(0,0,0);
color red = color(255,0,0);
color[] pointColour = new color[24];

//standalone method (at top outside of draw and setup)
void pointMaker(color colour, int pointX, int pointY){
  fill(colour);
  ellipse(pointX,pointY,pointSize,pointSize);
}

void setup(){
  size(200,200);
  background(255);
  for(int i:pointColour){//setup pointColour array at BEGINNING of setup
  pointColour[i] = white;
  }
}

void draw(){

  // draw hammer;
  fill(0);
  stroke(0);
  strokeWeight(6);
  line(128,hammerPos+10,148,hammerPos-12);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(125,hammerPos+13,129,hammerPos+11);
  strokeWeight(8);
  line(115,hammerPos+5,130,hammerPos+20);

  hammerPending = hammerPending + hammerVel;
  if (hammerPending > jump){
    hammerPos = hammerPos + hammerPending;
    hammerPending = 0;
    }

  for(int i = 0;i<24;i++){//refreshes 24 circles in white(invisible) constantly in draw until a color is changed
    pointMaker(pointColour[i], pointX, pointY); 
    pointX += pointIntervX;
    if(pointX>pointIntervX*4){
      pointX = pointIntervX;
      if(pointY<pointIntervY*6){
      pointY += pointIntervY;
      }
    }
  }

  if(hammerPos>height){
     hammerPos = 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `for` loop in `draw()` is executed in the context where `strokeWeight(8)` is still in force. You are seeing nothing but stroke. A simple fix would be to put the line `strokeWeight(1);` at the beginning of the definition of `pointMaker`.

When you do that, you see another bug. `for(int i:pointColour)` doesn't do what you think it does. You are iterating over the default *elements* (not the indices) of the array `pointColour` -- all of which are `0`. Thus what you are doing in that loop is 24 times in a row setting the first element of that array to `white`, leaving the other 23 equal to 0, which is equal to `black`. Hence after fixing the `strokeWeight` bug you are left with a grid of 1 white and 23 black circles. You should either initialize the array when you create it or in `setup()` loop over the indices rather than the elements by using `for(int i = 0; i < pointColour.length; i++) {`

**On Edit**: To clarify what I meant by index vs. element: `pointColour` was declared as `color[24]`. Thus `for(int i: pointColour)` doesn't really make sense. Using that type of iteration it should be `for(color i: pointColour)`. The only reason that what you wrote isn't a syntax error is that Processing's color data type seems to be an alias for a 32-bit int. The indices in `pointColour` are always the 24 integers 0,1,...,23. The elements of `pointColour` are whatever 24 colors that you happen to store in that array. In `pointColour[2] = color(0,0,255)` the index is 2 but the element is the color blue

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what's the difference between elements and indices in this context? Like how do "for(int i:x)" and "for(int i = 0;i<x;i++)" differ here in what they do exactly?